# Change default drive/partition/folder for user profiles in Windows 10 Pro during installation

Tags: windows-10

I want all user profiles to be created on my 2nd hard drive.

I know I can move them AFTER installation but I'm wondering if there is a way to set it during installation cause the very first account will be created in `C:\Users` and I want it created in `D:\Users`.

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Ah. Nice. Thank you!